# Eliminate row by key time column and sort

Tags: pandas, csv, row

Iam newbie in python. I have numerous data. I need to eliminate some of them by time. I have "first" and "last" appear ID. example ID_A first appeared at 17:31:14 and last appeared at 17:31:25.

my data looks like this:

```
 df
 ID         Time
 ID_A   17:31:14
 ID_A   17:31:25
 ID_B   10:16:55
 ID_B   15:50:15
 ID_C   12:34:57
 ID_C   12:41:07
 ID_D   15:37:47
 ID_D   15:37:56
 ID_E   16:25:00
 ID_E   18:37:13
 ID_F   11:35:05
 ID_F   11:40:15
```

I want to eliminate the ID's based on the time. I consider dropping the ID's row data first and last appear less than 2 minutes and above than 60 minutes. After eliminating, I want to sort the IDs by the time value.

my expected result looks like this:

```
ID          Time
ID_F    11:35:05
ID_F    11:40:15
ID_C    12:34:57
ID_C    12:41:07
```

please help me on how to do that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `ptp` from `numpy` , then using `isin` after `between`

```
import numpy as np

df.Time=pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)
s=df.groupby('ID')['Time'].apply(np.ptp).dt.total_seconds().between(2*60,90*60)
df_sub=df.loc[df.ID.isin(s[s].index)]
df_sub
Out[35]: 
      ID     Time
4   ID_C 12:34:57
5   ID_C 12:41:07
10  ID_F 11:35:05
11  ID_F 11:40:15
```

Now let us look at the sort part , i am using `transform` to get the min of each group ID, the using `argsort` get the position

```
df_sub=df_sub.iloc[df_sub.groupby('ID')['Time'].transform('min').argsort()]
Out[38]: 
      ID     Time
10  ID_F 11:35:05
11  ID_F 11:40:15
4   ID_C 12:34:57
5   ID_C 12:41:07
```